# SEGV: invalig write of size 8 when adding a node to the end of a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, append, singly-linked-list, segmentation-fault

I've got this function:

```
int  list_add_elem_at_back(list_t *front_ptr, double elem)
{
        list_t  item = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
        list_t  tmp = *front_ptr;

        if (item == NULL)
                return (0);
        item->value = elem;
        item->next = NULL;
        while (tmp != NULL)
                tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = item;
        return (1);
}
```

which is supposed to add a node to the back of the list starting with `t_list *front_ptr`.

**FYI:** `list_t` is an alias for `node_t *`.

When executing it, I get a SegV crash, and the Valgrind logs are the following:

```
==3814== Invalid write of size 8
==3814==    at 0x4006C1: list_add_elem_at_back (simple_list.c:63)
==3814==    by 0x400A83: populate_list (simple_list.c:181)
==3814==    by 0x400B5C: main (simple_list.c:202)
==3814==  Address 0x521f048 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==3814==    at 0x4C2FB6B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==3814==    by 0x40067D: list_add_elem_at_back (simple_list.c:56)
==3814==    by 0x400A83: populate_list (simple_list.c:181)
==3814==    by 0x400B5C: main (simple_list.c:202)
==3814== 
==3814== Invalid write of size 8
==3814==    at 0x4006EF: list_add_elem_at_back (simple_list.c:66)
==3814==    by 0x400A83: populate_list (simple_list.c:181)
==3814==    by 0x400B5C: main (simple_list.c:202)
==3814==  Address 0x8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

The lines 63 and 66 are `item->next = NULL;` and `tmp->next = item;`, which make me think it comes from the way I allocated (or didn't ?) my memory for the "next" nodes, but I cannot find out what's wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't like the idea of `list_t` being `node_t*` because it obfuscates the `*`, which is rather important to see with this kind of code. You get confusing code; bad idea.

Comment: I know and it also bothers me, but I'm asked to use this format and cannot do any differently.

Comment: Why talk about line 62 and 65 and not 63 and 66?

Comment: Oh yeah, the valgrind is from another try, after I added two `malloc(sizeof(list_t));` before each xx->next,.
Fixing it now.

Comment: `list_t  item = malloc(sizeof *item);` - develop a habit of doing it this way. Avoid using type names under `sizeof`. And lose the bad habit of hiding pointer types under typedef names. Sometimes it is justified, but not here.

Comment: @AnT Very good idea indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others said, it is a very bad idea to obfuscate `node_t *` into `list_t`.

---

Your first error is:

```
list_t  item = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
```

which is equivalent to

```
node_t *item = malloc(sizeof(node_t *));
```

You're allocating the size of a pointer, not the size of a `node_t` instance.

You should have

```
node_t *item = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
```

---

Your second error comes from the way you browse your list.

```
list_t tmp = *front_ptr;
while (tmp != NULL)
    tmp = tmp->next;
tmp->next = item;
```

Your while loop stops when tmp is NULL, which means the next line (`tmp->next = item;`) does `NULL->next = item;`, which of course is invalid.

Also, if *front_ptr is NULL (for example, when you try to create the first element), it skips the loop (which is normal), and generates the same issue.

Here's what I would do:

```
int  list_add_elem_at_back(node_t **front_ptr, double elem)
{
    node_t *item = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    node_t *tmp;

    if (item == NULL) {
        return (0);
    }
    item->value = elem;
    item->next = NULL;

    if (*front_ptr == NULL) {
        *front_ptr = item;
    } else {
        tmp = *front_ptr;
        while (tmp->next != NULL)
            tmp = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = item;
    }
    return (1);
}
```

Comment: Almost exactly what I ended up doing. I kept searching and trying everything that came to my mind considering what had been said here.

Answer (score 3):

You're allocating `sizeof(list_t)`, which is a pointer. You must do:

```
malloc(sizeof(node_t));
```

Exactly the result of this shitty idea to hide away the `*`.

The second issue: When `head` is `NULL`, then you're passing a null pointer to the function with `&head`. Apparently `next` is at offset `0x08`. Because `tmp` is `0`, `tmp->next` is at `0 + 0x08`. A quick check can be done with `head = malloc(sizeof(node_t))`.

Comment: The first error has disappeared, The second one (on `tmp->next = item`) remains though.

Comment: That seems (a similar) issue with `front_ptr` you passed in. There's an invalid address in `tmp` with value `0x08`. That mistake is not in this code.

Comment: it is a list_t *,  passed through another function with &head, declared as a list_t in the main.

How do I fix the second one then ?

Comment: How was memory allocated for this `head`?

Comment: head = NULL. That's all I have. I know I'm trying to access NULL->next, but I can't find a way to get around this, knowing I can only edit the contents of the list_add_elem_at_back() function

Comment: @ilomax See extended answer why you get address `0x08` as the failed address for the second issue.

Comment: By head, do you mean front_ptr (the 1st parameter) or the variable set in the main() ? Since I can't edit the main, I think you get why I'm aksing.

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet

```
int  add_node(list_t *front_ptr, double elem)
{
        list_t  item = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                ^^^^^^
```

does not make sense, because there is allocated a pointer instead of a structure of the type `node_t`.

I think you mean

```
int  list_add_elem_at_back(list_t *front_ptr, double elem)
{
        list_t  item = malloc(sizeof(*list_t));
        int success = item != NULL;

        if ( success )
        {
            item->value = elem;
            item->next = NULL;

            while ( *front_ptr != NULL) front_ptr = &( *front_ptr )->next;

            *front_ptr = item;
        }

        return success;
}
```

And the function can be called the following way

```
list_add_elem_at_back( &head, value );
```

where `head` is the initial node of the list.

In general it is a bad idea to make such an alias for a pointer. It makes difficult to understand your code.

Also if you are going to append a node to the end of a singly-linked list then you should declared a two-sided singly-linked list. For a one-sided singly-linked list this function is inefficient.